# Streaming radio in web browser

Tags: flash, web, stream, m3u, asx

I have a homepage for streaming diffrent online web radios. At the moment I'm using the Windows Media Player Plugin but many users report problems with this plugin/solution ([details about the current solution here](http://www.streamalot.com/wm-embed.shtml)).

Now I'm looking for a new solution: Does someone knows a flash (or other) based software for streaming web radios in the following file formats? I've already tried it with JWPlayer but it didn't work well for all the streaming file formats.

Used file formats:

- .pls
- .asx
- .m3u
- .mp3